# Was there an Australian version of the movie "I Now Pronounce You Chuck and Larry"?

Tags: production, alternate-version, i-now-pronounce-you-chuck-and-larry

I'm pretty sure the premise of two firemen pretending to be gay to get their proper pension benefits was the main premise of both *I Now Pronounce You Chuck and Larry* and some Australian movie.

The wiki of *I Now Pronounce You Chuck and Larry* does not mention anything, but I'm certain the premise of that movie was stolen from the Australian movie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The wiki of *I Now Pronounce You Chuck and Larry* does not mention anything

If by "wiki", you mean [the film's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Now_Pronounce_You_Chuck_%26_Larry), then it actually *does* mention what you're referring to (emphasis mine):

> In November 2007, the producers of the Australian film *Strange Bedfellows* initiated legal action against Universal Studios for copyright violation. *Strange Bedfellows* was released three years before. In comparison, the films have 100 similar plot points. Both movie plots deal with two firemen, who pretend to be a gay couple for financial reasons, are investigated, and then have to deal with the situation with their friends and community. **The suit was withdrawn in April 2008 after the producers of *Strange Bedfellows* received an early draft of *Chuck & Larry* that predated their film, and they were satisfied that they had not been plagiarized.**

So there *is* an Australian movie with the same premise as *I Now Pronounce You Chuck and Larry*, but there is no evidence that one "stole" the idea from the other, and strong evidence that the films were in fact conceived independently of one another.